# Local extremes for quartic multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative

I have the function :$\ f(x,y)= x^4 +y^4-8xy $, and I have to find it's local extreme points. I computed the partial derivatives :

- $\ f_x= 4x^3-8y$
- $\ f_y= 4y^3-8x $
- $\ f_{xx}= 12x^2 $
- $\ f_{yy}= 12y^2 $
- $\ f_{xy}= -8 $

Then,by solving for $\ fx =0 $ i found that $\ y= x^3/2 $  ,and replacing in $\ fy=0 $ found $\ x= 0 , x=2 , x=-2 $. Now,when solving $\ y= x^3/2 $ for each value of ***x***,besides (2,4), (-2,-4), should I also compute for $\ x= 0 $ ? That doesn't make a lot of sense to me since I should divide 0 at 2. Besides this , when i compute D using the formula $\ D = (f_{xx})(f_{yy})-(f_{xy})^2 $ which gives me $\ (12x^2)(12y^2)-64 $ and replace for the points I found, I get really high values. Could anyone please take a look over the exercise and tell me if I'm doing something wrong somewhere or maybe if I'm skipping some steps? Also, any suggestions about improving the method are more than welcomed.